# How can I find out what filesystem a particular directory is on

Tags: filesystems

I have a system with symlinks EVERYWHERE, so given a particular directory, is there a simple way to find out what mountpoint this directory is on?
Particularly interested in solaris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df dirname
```

It should give the filesystem and mount point of the **target** of the symlink.

If you want to know the mount point and filesystem of the symlink itself:

```
df $(dirname /path/to/dirname)
```

<sup>(That's the command `dirname` and a dummy directory named "dirname", confusingly enough.)</sup>

Comment: yeah, that doesn't help much, the symlinks go forwards and backwards and there are often many ways to get to the same place.

Comment: Did you actually try this?  Because it does what you're asking in your question.  Seems to work on my OpenSolaris box...but it's running everything on ZFS but I don't think that matters.

Comment: I just tested with symlinks 3 hops deep between two different zfs pools and multiple filesystems on OpenSolaris and df was properly reporting where the actual directory is.

Comment: ahhh. I tried the first bit, missed the second bit.
What I didn't realize was that df does this itself. My bad. I thought you had to give it a real filesystem only.

Answer (score 0):

I know this provides a little more information than you requested. But you could make a simple C program using the realpath() library call.  I have done this before to find out exactly where a specific file was.  From there it should be a simple matter of determining the filesystem.  A sample program would look like:

```
 /*
 * realpath - a program to find the real path
 */

 #include <limits.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include        <stdio.h>


 main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
 {
    void exit();
    char realx[10000];

    printf("\nORIGINAL PATH:\t%s\n",argv[1]);

    printf("Real PATH:\t%s\n",realpath(argv[1],realx));

    exit(0);

 }
```

Comment: Or you could use `readlink -f`

Comment: BTW- readlink is not present on solaris systems